# Update DeltaTable on column type ArrayType(): add element to array

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

I need to perform an Update on a Delta Table adding elements to a column of ArrayType(StringType()) which is initialized empty.

**Before Update**
|Col 1 StringType()|Col 2 StringType()| Col 1 ArrayType()|
| -|-|-|
|val|val|[]|

**AfterUpdate**
|Col 1 StringType()|Col 2 StringType()|Col 1 ArrayType()|
|-|-|-|
|val|val|['value']|

I'm using `DeltaTable.Update` statement but the syntaxes I tried fail - not sure if `set` command supports this kind of operation.

```
schema = StructType([ 
StructField("Load_id", StringType(), True),
StructField("Task_id", StringType(), True),
StructField("Task_output", StringType(), True),
StructField("Task_output_detail", ArrayType(StringType()), True),
StructField("Execution_ts", TimestampType(), True), 
StructField("Task_status", StringType(), True)]) 

#some code to init data and materialize the Delta Table

Task_output_detailt_new = "Invalid value" 
Log_table = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, path) 

#syntax 1 
Log_table.update( 
condition = (col("Load_id")== Load_id) & (col("Task_id")== Task_id), 
set = { "Task_output": lit(Task_output), "Task_output_detail": Task_output_detailt_new, "Execution_ts": lit(Execution_ts), "Task_status": lit('Closed')})

#syntax 2
Log_table.update( 
condition = (col("Load_id")== Load_id) & (col("Task_id")== Task_id), 
set = { "Task_output": lit(Task_output), "Task_output_detail": array_append(Task_output_detail,Task_output_detailt_new), "Execution_ts": lit(Execution_ts), "Task_status": lit('Closed')})
```

Does anyone know a "smart" solution or correct syntaxt to achieve that? I want to avoid deleting the raw and creating a new one since I have to perform multiple updates / appends.

Thanks!